# How to find from where SQL syntax error of ; and ) is coming?

Tags: sql, syntax, unpivot, cross-apply, tableau-desktop

I see an error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ';'.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

when trying to run the following on Custom SQL on Tableau Desktop

```
SELECT SbjNum,
  indicatorname,
  indicatorvalue
FROM
    stg_a1ee6_4c7096aa_1
CROSS apply
    (
        values
('Q1_1', Q1_1),
('Q1_2', Q1_2),
('Q1_3', Q1_3),
('Q1_3OE', Q1_3OE)
) c (indicatorname, indicatorvalue);
```

I am unable to find where the syntax is wrong

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the semi-colon.  Have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau will not like the semi-colon.  Try removing it.

If that doesn't work, copy and paste it into SQL.  Does it work?

I don't see an issue with your parentheses (every open seems to have a close).  It may be easier to find this problem in SQL SSMS.